# How to create a Python script that grabs text from one site and reposts it to another?

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to create a Python script that grabs digits of Pi from this site:
http://www.piday.org/million.php
and reposts them to this site:
http://www.freelove-forum.com/index.php
I am NOT spamming or playing a prank, it is an inside joke with the creator and webmaster, a belated Pi day celebration, if you will.

Comment: Maybe better suited for SO, perhaps? At any rate what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Import urllib2 and BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

specify the url and fetch using urllib2

```
url = 'http://www.piday.org/million.php'
response = urlopen(url)
```

and then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)  which uses the tags in the page to build a dictionary, and then you can query the dictionary with the relevant tags that define the data to extract what you want.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

pi = soup.findAll('TAG')
```

where 'TAG' is the relevant tag you want to find that identifies where pi is.

Specify what you want to print out

```
out = '<html><body>'+pi+'</html></body>
```

You can then write this to a HTML file that you serve, using pythons inbuilt file operations.

```
f = open('file.html', 'w')
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

You then serve the file 'file.html' using your webserver.

If you don't want to use BeautifulSoup you could use re and urllib, but it is not as 'pretty' as BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

When you post a post, it's done with a `POST` request which is sent to the server. Look at the code on your site:

```
<form action="enter.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="post">Enter text here</textarea> 
</form>
```

You are going to send a `POST` request with a parameter of `post` (bad object naming IMO), which is your text.

As for the site you are grabbing from, if you look at the source code, the Pi is actually inside of an `<iframe>` with this URL:

```
 http://www.piday.org/includes/pi_to_1million_digits_v2.html
```

Looking at *that* source code, you can see that the page is just a single `<p>` tag directly descending from a `<body>` tag (the site doesn't have the `<!DOCTYPE>`, but I'll include one):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>3.1415926535897932384...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since HTML is a form of XML, you will need to use an XML parser to parse the webpage. I use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), as it works *very* well with malformed or invalid XML, but even better with perfectly valid HTML.

To download the actual page, which you would feed into the XML parser, you can use Python's built-in [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). For the `POST` request, I'd use Python's standard [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

So a complete example would be this:

```
import urllib, httplib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Downloads and parses the webpage with Pi
page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.piday.org/includes/pi_to_1million_digits_v2.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# Extracts the Pi. There's only one <p> tag, so just select the first one
pi_list = soup.findAll('p')[0].contents
pi = ''.join(str(s).replace('\n', '') for s in pi_list).replace('<br />', '')

# Creates the POST request's body. Still bad object naming on the creator's part...
parameters = urllib.urlencode({'post':      pi, 
                               'name':      'spammer',
                               'post_type': 'confession',
                               'school':    'all'})

# Crafts the POST request's header.
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Accept':       'text/plain'}

# Creates the connection to the website
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('freelove-forum.com:80')
connection.request('POST', '/enter.php', parameters, headers)

# Sends it out and gets the response
response = connection.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason

# Finishes the connections
data = response.read()
connection.close()
```

But if you are using this for a malicious purpose, do know that the server logs all IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `urllib2` module which come in any Python distribution.

It allows you to open an URL as you were opening a file on the filesystem. So you can fetch the PI data with

```
pi_million_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.piday.org/million.php")
```

parse the resulting file which will be the HTML code of the webpage you see in your browser.

Then you should use the right URL for your website to POST with PI.